# Help with calculating a sum of all previous rows in each subsequent row in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following view which calculates the percentage increase of the site resources used for each date per site id:

[image: table with percentage increases]

What I'm trying to accomplish, is to add an extra column which will show the sum total of all previous percentage increases on each row. So the final table should look like this:

[image: table with total sums column]

Column1 here is just to further clarify the exact idea I'm trying to accomplish here. Each row in the 'total percentage by date' column should display the sum total of the current row + all the previous rows' 'percentage increase for date' values.

All solutions I have found so far for this won't work in postgres. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `SUM(percentage) OVER (PARTITION BY site_id ORDER BY date) `

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross apply`

```
SELECT d.*, di.p
FROM Data d
JOIN LATERAL (
SELECT SUM(di.Persent) AS p
FROM Data di
WHERE di.AccesDate <= d.AccesDate
AND di.SiteID = d.SiteID
) di ON TRUE ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but CROSS APPLY is not a postgresql statement. Thus I cannot use it unfortunately.

Comment: I edit my answer.